# Add UIImageView as a subview to UIKeyboard - userInteractionEnabled?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard, uiimageview

I have a little problem with adding a subview to my UIKeyboard. I can successfully locate my keyboard and add an uiimageview to it, but unfortunately the button under the image view still can be touched. I just wanted to make it a color overlay, which would hide the unneeded keys and also make them untouchable :)

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong? The UIImageView displays correctly, but the buttons still can be tapped... :(

```
- (UIView *)findKeyboard {

    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIKeyboard.  
    UIView *foundKeyboard = nil;
    for (UIView __strong *possibleKeyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

        // iOS 4 sticks the UIKeyboard inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            possibleKeyboard = [[possibleKeyboard subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        }                                                                                

        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
            foundKeyboard = possibleKeyboard;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundKeyboard;
}   

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {  

    UIImageView *overlayView;
    UIView *keyboardView = [self findKeyboard];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"keyboardOverlay.png"];
    overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [overlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, overlayView.frame.size.width, overlayView.frame.size.height)];
    newView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    newView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    [newView addSubview:overlayView];
    [keyboardView insertSubview:newView atIndex:40];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User interaction being disabled means that touches are passed straight through. Enable it, but don't have any gesture recognisers or actions, and it will swallow all touches.

Comment: Oh, I am really dumb. I totally forgot about that... Thank you really much :)